# C/C++ rand() function for biased expectation

Tags: random, probability

I am using `<stdlib.h> rand()` function to generate 100 random integers within range [0 ... 9]. I used the following way to generate them on equal distribution,

```
int random_numbers[100];
for(register int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    random_numbers[i] = rand() % 10;
}
```

This is working fine. But now I want to get 100 numbers where I want around 50% of those numbers to be 5. How do I do that?

***Extended Problem***

I want to get 100 numbers. What if I want 50% of those number will be between 0~2. I mean 50 percent of those number will consists only with number 0, 1, 2. How to do that?

I am expecting generalised steps which can be applied beyond the boundary of 10 or 100.

Comment: However you want. For example, you could first pick a random number that's 0 or 1. If it's 0, then pick 0, 1, or 2 to output. If it's 1, then output 3 through 9 using the same method. Just code what you want.

Comment: You need to design your own and probably call it - `semi-pseudo-random` algorithm.

Comment: why downvotes? at least give me a clue if its very easy.

Comment: So 9 of the numbers should be 0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 and the 9 other should be 5. Looks like 18 outcomes. Hmmmm.,

Comment: So, do you want *exactly* 50% of these numbers to be 0-2 or *around* 50% of these numbers to be 0-2? Your question suggests both at the same time. Make up your mind.

Comment: @AnT I want around 50% of the numbers 5. all other numbers to be distributed equally for other 50%.

Comment: "What if I want 50% of those number ..." lacks clarity: what are _those number(s)_?  50% of the 100 numbers?  Sounds like 50% are "between 0~2" and 50% are 5.

Comment: @chux please read the question carefully. I think all information u need to answer the question for are given... its already mentioned that total numbers are 100. so 50% of those number means 50 out of 100. Simple math isn't it?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan The point is that it seem unreasonable to want 50% of the numbers as 5 and 50% of the numbers as 0, 1, 2 - that is only 4 outcomes. So perhaps you seek something else.  The info might all be there, but it is open to various interpretations other than what one person thinks.  Asking for clarification and receiving "read the question carefully" does not  advance the cause as much as simple providing more explanation or examples.

Comment: @chux Sorry if u misunderstood. Actually 2nd problem was in different context thats why I labeled with Extended Problem. In the extended version I did not mention about 5. Expectation is only for a group of items rather single item in the initial version.

Comment: @chux anyway I rephrased a sentence which might clarify more. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, how about choosing a random number between `0` and `17`, and if the number is greater than `9`, change it to `5`?

For 0 - 17, you would get a distribution like

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
```

Code:

```
int random_numbers[100];
for(register int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    random_numbers[i] = rand() % 18;
    if (random_numbers[i] > 9) {
        random_numbers[i] = 5;
    }
}
```

You basically add a set of numbers beyond your desired range that, when translated to `5` give you equal numbers of `5` and `non-5`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get *around* 50% of these numbers to be in `[0, 2]` range you can split the full range of `rand()` into two equal halves and then use the same `%`-based technique to map the first half to `[0, 2]` range and the second half to `[3, 9]` range.

```
int random_numbers[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  int r = rand();
  random_numbers[i] = r <= RAND_MAX / 2 ? r % 3 : r % 7 + 3;
}
```

To to get *around* 50% of these numbers to be `5` a similar technique will work. Just map the second half to `[0, 9]` range with `5` excluded

```
int random_numbers[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  int r = rand();

  if (r <= RAND_MAX / 2)
    r = 5;
  else if ((r %= 9) >= 5)
    ++r;

  random_numbers[i] = r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easy to solve the particular problem of 50% using the techniques mentioned by other answers. Let us try to answer the question for a general case - 
Let us say you want a distribution where you want the numbers `{A1, A2, .. An}` with the percentages `{P1, P2, .. Pn}` and sum of `Pi` is `100%` (and all the percentages are integers, if not it can be adjusted).

We will create an array of 100 size and fill it with the numbers `A1-An`.

```
int distribution[100];
```

Now we fill each number, it's percentage number of times.

```
int postion = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for( int j = 0; j < P[i]; j++) {
        // Add a check here to make sure the sum hasn't crossed 100
        distribution[position] = A[i];
        position ++;
    }
}
```

Now that this initialization is done once, you can draw a random number as -

```
int number = distribution[rand() % 100];
```

In case your percentages are not integers but say you want precision of `0.1%`, you can create an array of `1000` instead of `100`.

Comment: what if the sum crossed 100?

Comment: should it be `int number = distribution[rand() % 100];` or `int number = distribution[rand() % position];` ?

Comment: At the end of the loop, position should be `100`. Because those are percentages. The sum should be `100`.

Answer (score 1):

In both case, the goal is 50% selected from one set and 50% from another.  Code could call `rand()` and uses some bits (one) for choosing the group and the remaining bits for value selection.

If the range of numbers needed is much smaller than `RAND_MAX`, a first attempt could use:

```
int rand_special_50percent(int n, int special) {
  int r = rand();
  int r_div_2 = r/2;
  if (r%2) {
    return special;
  }
  int y = r_div_2%(n-1);  // 9 numbers left 
  if (y >= special) y++;
  return y;
}

int rand_low_50percent(int n, int low_special) {
  int r = rand();
  int r_div_2 = r/2;
  if (r%2) {
    return r_div_2%(low_special+1);
  }
  return r_div_2%(n - low_special) + low_special + 1;
}
```

Sample

```
int r5 = rand_special_50percent(10, 5);

int preferred_low_value_max = 2;
int r012 = rand_low_50percent(10, preferred_low_value_max);
```

---

Advanced:

With `n` above `RAND_MAX/2`, additional calls to `rand()` are needed.

When using `rand()%n`, unless `(RAND_MAX+1u)%n == 0` (`n` is a divisor of `RAND_MAX+1`), a bias is introduced.  The above code does not compensate for that.

Answer (score 1):

**C++11 solution** (not optimal but easy)

[`std::piecewise_constant_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution) can generate random real numbers (float or double) for given intervals and weights for the each interval.
Not optimal because ***this solution is generating double and converting double to int***. Also ***getting exactly 50 from [0,3) 100 samples is not guaranteed but for around 50 samples is guaranteed.***

For your case : 2 intervals - `[0,3), [3,100)` and their weights `[1,1]`
Equal weights, so ~50% of the numbers from `[0,3)` and ~50% from `[3,100)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    std::vector<double> intervals{0,  3, 3, 100};
    std::vector<double> weights{  1,  0,  1};
    std::piecewise_constant_distribution<> d(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), weights.begin());

    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for(int n=0; n<100; ++n) {
        ++hist[(int)d(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << p.first << " : generated " << p.second << " times"<< '\n';
    }
}
```

---

```
Output:
0 : generated 22 times
1 : generated 19 times
2 : generated 16 times
4 : generated 1 times
5 : generated 2 times
8 : generated 1 times
12 : generated 1 times
17 : generated 1 times
19 : generated 1 times
22 : generated 2 times
23 : generated 1 times
25 : generated 1 times
29 : generated 1 times
30 : generated 2 times
31 : generated 1 times
36 : generated 1 times
38 : generated 1 times
44 : generated 1 times
45 : generated 1 times
48 : generated 1 times
49 : generated 1 times
51 : generated 1 times
52 : generated 1 times
53 : generated 1 times
57 : generated 2 times
58 : generated 3 times
62 : generated 1 times
65 : generated 2 times
68 : generated 1 times
71 : generated 1 times
76 : generated 2 times
77 : generated 1 times
85 : generated 1 times
90 : generated 1 times
94 : generated 1 times
95 : generated 1 times
96 : generated 2 times
```